# IE:"This.container" is null or not an object

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

I have this error in IE7 not in Firefox3

it says "This.container" is null or not an object

at line 77 of character 3 of php file.

The line 77 is as follows:

```
<input name="news_title_txt" type="text" class="fieldcell_" id="news_title_txt" size="50"  ></td>
```

Comment: Line numbers for JavaScript errors are notoriously incorrect, as seems to be the case here. You need to provide more information before we can help you.

Comment: The line 77 in the unparsed php file doesn't tell us anything. You'll have to show us line 77 as sent to the browser, along with the surrounding rows. Actually it would be preferable if you could show us the entire script.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I would try is try `this` not `This`.